# K&R Section 1.5.3 Line Counting

Tags: c

i just answered a question from K&R Which was "Write a program that counts blanks , tabs, and newlines"

And Heres my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
 /* Program  counts Number of lines, Spaces, and Tabs from user input*/

 int c, nl,tabs,spaces;
 spaces = 0;
 tabs = 0;
 nl = 0;

 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
          if(c =='\t')
                 ++tabs;
                  else if(c==' ')
                       ++spaces;
                        else if (c == '\n')
                                 ++nl;

 printf("Newlines %d\nTabs %d\nSpaces %d", nl, tabs, spaces);
return 0;
}
```

The Output runs exactly the same..
but the book got a different answer.
So am i Incorrect?

Comment: Its not necessary to write program exactly as in book . It can be done in many ways .

Comment: Thanks, i thought i was wrong

Comment: The number of newline and the number of rows  Note that they doesn't necessarily coincide.

Comment: Yes, do you have any sort of fix for this? Bellieve me when i say ive worked on it for awhile

Answer (score 1):

As you declared yourself a learned, I will just add some remarks.

You should always declare `main` as `int main(...)`. In early (K&R) times, every function that did not have a proper declaration was assumed to return int, but it is deprecated in modern versions.

`while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` is correct as `c` is declared as int. But your indentation is misleading: it is better to write `else if` or `else` at same level as the original if.

Last (even if it is rather a matter of taste), you did not put curly brackets around any of the blocs. It is correct because there is one single statement after each `if`, and in that case, the full `if ... else ...` counts for a single instruction. But this would be a nightmare for future maintainers in a real world program. My advice is to always write curly braces if you indent, and only omit them when the instruction is written on same line as the if.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification & i wll use braces on future coding. Thanks again for the Info it helped.